# Simple minimum component RF Amplifier Design

Tags: equipment-design, amplifier, vacuum-tubes

Looking for advice/assistance in Retrofitting sans Cabinet Antique 2 and 3 Dialer 1920's TRF tube radios to operate with low safe Plate voltages.Both Hollow State and Solid State. The plan is to remove all antique high voltage tubes.
We need a low-cost minimal component Small Signal RF amplifier Design.

Comment: Welcome to hamSE! How much power output do you want? What plate voltage do you consider to be safe?

Comment: Hello Jordan, I added your name, email, and callsign information to [your profile](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/17263/jjdobrikin?tab=profile) for you. :-)

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would edit your question to include more details. As it is, it's difficult to answer. Also, since we are all unpaid volunteers here and our time is limited, it is expected that users will do a reasonable amount of research before asking a question here. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? :-)